# clarifications regarding autolayout in iOS

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have searched the iOS developer library and cant find the answer.
what does vertical/horizontal spacing mean?
What exactly is the "default" (when you check the box "standard" in constraint attribute editing panel) value of a constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spacing is distance between two sibilings subviews, standard means that autolayout will apply the standard spacing. Standards are defined by aqua interface design, that means 8 points between views and 20 poits from leading,trailing,top,bottom of superview.

Answer (score 1):

**Vertical spacing:** it means the vertical distance between control and the border of view.
     It may be above or below the control.

**Horizontal spacing:** it means the Horizontal distance between control and the border of view.
     It may be right or left the control.

**Constraint** is nothing but the condition that should not be voileted during the UI presentation.
It is something like when I am defining a constraint of 50pxl for UILabel for vertical top spacing then my label cannot be within the top 50 pxl area.

When you checkmark the standard then `NSAutoLayout` organise your controls according to apples standard user interface guidelines.

Resizing can be done on **priority of constraint** basis.

Answer (score 0):

Vertical spacing means just what its name implies -- it a space constraint in the vertical direction between 2 objects. Likewise for horizontal.

What "standard" is depends on the constraint -- if you just uncheck the "standard" box, a number will appear in the text field, so you can see what standard is. It's 20 for instance between the side of a view and a subview.